# AngularJs - Unable to call click JavaScript click function of a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've two bootstrap tabs where I'm showing list on the first Tab and on the second tab there will be textboxes for adding new record.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs naviborder">
   <li class="active" ng-click="showTasksList()">
      <a class="icontab" data-target="#divTasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-click="addTask()" id="liCreateTask">
      <a id="aAddTask" class="icontab" data-target="#divCreateTask" data-toggle="tab">Create Task</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now on the list, I've some edit button and on clicking that, I will populate the textboxes in the second tab and show the second tab automatically.

Now, My problem is : I'm able to populate the textboxes but uanble to switch to the second tab.

My AngularJs Code :

```
$scope.EditFieldForceTask = function (TaskData) {           
   $scope.TaskEditMode = true;
   $scope.TaskContactName = TaskData.CONTACT_NAME;
   $scope.TaskContactNumber = TaskData.CONTACT_NUMBER;
   $('#aAddTask').click();
   //$scope.tab2Click();
}
```

Upon calling this `$('#aAddTask').click();`, I'm getting three errors like

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply 
at Error (native)
```

I've also tried to define a ng-click event to that a tag, but even that's not working.

But when I try to call the function `$('#aAddTask').click();` from console, it's working fine.

Can anyone please tell me the mistake I'm doing?

Comment: I think Your id aAddTask is not accessible inside EditFieldForceTask function.

Comment: why cant you call the method instead of simulating the click?

Comment: Why cant u just call the addTask function in EditFieldForceTask? Or try calling ur code in $timeout(function() {$('#aAddTask').click();})

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1x6pmexs/2/ ?

Comment: @blessenm : Finally, the timeout seems to be working.Thank you very much. `setTimeout(function () { $('#abcAddTask').click(); }, 200);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute a click function which may be triggering a digest cycle while a digest cycle is already in progress.

You can delay your click function to be executed after current digest cycle is executed using $timeout or setTimeout.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $('#aAddTask').click();
});
```